# How do I avoid WebSocketHandshakeException: Requested subprotocol(s) not supported

Tags: heroku, playframework, websocket, http-headers

I am using websockets in the play framework.
I would like to use a subprotocol, i.e. set the header Sec-WebSocket-Protocol to a protocol, which is not supported by jboss/Heroku:

```
org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.WebSocketHandshakeException: Requested subprotocol(s) not supported
```

I am implementing the protocol I specify in Sec-WebSocket-Protocol, and for this reason the server should accept the sub-protocol.
I run into this error even before I reach the first breakpoint in my code.
Can I configure jboss/Heroku to accept the given sub protocol?
And if so - how?

Thanks,
-Louise

Comment: Same answer as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35886970/how-can-i-configure-subprotocol-for-netty-io/35887662#35887662