# How can I configure subprotocol for Netty io?

Tags: networking, playframework, websocket, netty

I am using websockets with Play framework.
When I try to set value to the HTTP header `Sec-WebSocket-Protocol`, e.g. "ocpp1.6" then I get the following exception:

```
[error] p.nettyException - Exception caught in Netty
org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.WebSocketHandshakeException: Requested subprotocol(s) not supported: ocpp1.6
```

I can see that the error occurs because the constructor's "subprotocols" parameter in `org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.WebSocketServerHandshakerFactory` is null.

Therefore how can I change this value and is it the only reason which causes the error?

Thanks,
-Louise

Comment: How are you creating your pipeline?

Comment: I am using the Play framework, so I am getting the communication out-of-the-box. I just discovered that it is the play.core.server.websocket.WebSocketHandshake class that sets the subprotocol parameter to null. How can I overwrite/work-around this Play behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

It seems it is a known bug that the Play framework did not support subprotocols, which should be fixed by version 2.2.1:

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/1722